# Where do I find system sounds?

Tags: notification, sound, system

After installing gm-notify I see the option of hearing a sound every time a new e-mail arrives in my Gmail inbox, but I don't know where Ubuntu (10.4) stores the system sounds to assign one. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 42):

```
/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts
```

would be a good place to find sounds for this purpose.

```
/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu
```

is a sound theme. Sound themes can be chosen in sound preferences. 'ubuntu' is the only sound theme installed by default (Edit: this was [removed in 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105441/how-to-change-which-sound-is-reproduced-for-terminal-bell)). I would advise against editing files in this folder directly. A better thing to do, if you wanted to edit the sounds in this folder, would be to copy it (perhaps to `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu-modified`) and change the index.theme file to have a different name.

```
sudo cp -R /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu-modified
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu-modified/index.theme
```

Once this is done, you can safely edit the sounds in `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu-modified`.

Comment: I see the sounds, and the sound config lets me turn up the "cheek-pop" sound - but don't see themes.

Comment: I was about to ask about the license these sounds have. Seems its [CC by SA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/ubuntu-sounds/+copyright) so it seems they can be used to make derivative works, like a song, from these sounds (:D)

Answer (score 4):

You can find the bulk of the system sounds here: `/usr/share/sounds/` with the majority of them being in `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo`

Answer (score 3):

```
/usr/share/sounds
```

If you remove/rename a sound, it should stop. Or you can replace it with an .ogg sound (.wav works too... I think...)

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I could already assign a system sound to gm-notify and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

For some sillier sounds (which I sometimes like to use for system events), you can also check here: `/usr/share/gnome-games/sounds`

You can download more system sounds for Gnome at [Gnome-look.org](https://www.gnome-look.org/search/projectSearchText/sounds), too.

Comment: I know this was posted over 6 years ago, but that link doesn't work - link rot.  It sure is best if you can post info for how to use sounds.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try

**Sound > Sound Effects**

I have mine switched off since I find sound effects annoying