# How do I make my own customized ubuntu sounds?

Tags: sound, themes

I'd like to be able to either make my own sound theme or perhaps find one that's completely customizable i.e. how windows sound is customizable from the get go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu uses freedesktop.org sound themes. For writing your own sound themes refer to the [Sound Theme Specification](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/sound-theme-spec). You can find sound themes on many sites, [this one](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=25&PHPSESSID=f6f66d16cb4a76ae803446b0f744bffd) appears to be one of the more popular ones.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1527/where-do-i-find-system-sounds) has some more detail on the files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the alert sound, or switch themes, in:

System->Preferences->Sounds

Comment: i wasnt talking about the alert sounds, i meant more of a theme. which by the way there is only ubuntu or no sounds avaible when you click to change.