# Notify PCM Volume change instead of Master?

Tags: volume-control, libnotify

I prefer to leave the Master volume at 100% and just adjust volume with PCM.

I used this [askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32383/adjust-pcm-volume) to separate the controlling of each of these channels.
Unfortunately the volume applet and notification pop-pup are linked to the master channel.

How can I change these to give me information on PCM audio channel instead of Master?

Answer (score 1):

I've found my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12766/adjust-volume-via-commandline-so-that-volume-notify-pops-up/12769#12769) in another ask Ubuntu answer.
If I use that script and change the mixer from 'Master' to 'PCM' I get a good pop-up notification of the PCM volume changes.