# Ubuntu 16.04 - Asus UX360U

Tags: 16.04, drivers, display, asus, touchscreen

I have a Asus UX360U with Ubuntu 16.04. Everything works so far, also webcam and microphone without any extra driver.
But the PC has on left side a volume hardware button (higher and lower). This is not working. Has anybody a idea which driver is required?

Further the PC has a Touchscreen, the Touchscreen self works. But if I flip the display the Screen doesn't turn. How can I configure this, the sensors are working.

And the last point is it possible that Ubuntu disables the Keyboard if I flip the Display?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could add a Custom shortcut on Keyboard settings, associating [those buttons to `xdotool key --clearmodifiers XF86AudioLowerVolume` and Raise](https://askubuntu.com/a/12767/349837).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think there is no current solution for that, as you can see from these current submitted bugs in launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1661864

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1661878