# Ringtones for computer

Tags: system-settings

All my other/previous computers (Mac and Windows) allowed me to import ringtones to replace the system sounds for things such as e-mail delivery. When searching the FAQ, I saw reference only to Ubuntu phones, but I want to reset my ringtones on my Ubuntu laptop computer. How can I do this?

Comment: They're called system sounds, not ringtones.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1527/where-do-i-find-system-sounds