# How to reproduce the notification message and sound of the Volume Up button?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, sound, shortcut-keys, notification

I know that the following command increases volume

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 10%+
```

This command only increases the volume, but does not show any GUI notifications. But, the default Volume Up key also gives GUI and sound notifications.

What commands are called when I press the Volume Up button?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what command is being invoked while pressing volume up button however I believe that it's not a single command. You can simulate and achieve same behavior by using three simple command:

1. To increase the volume as you know:

   ```
   amixer -D pulse sset Master 10%+
   ```
2. To send a notify:

   ```
   notify-send Volume volume has been increased by +10
   ```
3. To play a song:

   ```
   paplay '/usr/share/sounds/KDE-Window-All-Desktops-Not.ogg'
   ```

change the file address with anything you want, you can find different songs at:

```
/usr/share/sounds/
```

or run a simple search:

```
locate .ogg | grep /share
```

Comment: It's likely that the GUI doesn't call any command at all. It will make use of libraries.

Comment: @muru Exactly, and so can we!

Comment: So, how do I do that?!

Answer (score 0):

You‘re probably searching for the **X On-Screen Display library XOSD**. The package is called `xosd-bin` and the command `osd_cat` is used to display text, status bars etc. on the screen.

```
osd_cat -b percentage -P 20 -T Status: -f "-adobe-helvetica-bold-*-*--34-*-*-*-*"
```

displays

[image]

See [this German wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/XOSD/) for options and examples and [man osd_cat](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/osd_cat.1.html) for more.

---

As others already pointed out, sounds can be played using a player like `aplay`, `paplay`, `cvlc`, `mplayer`, `cmus`, …
 – [Where do I find system sounds?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1527/where-do-i-find-system-sounds)