# How to change which sound is reproduced for terminal bell?

Tags: gnome-terminal, 18.10, teminal-bell

Recently upgrade to 18.10 from 18.04, and using the terminal is becoming annoying: the new alert sound is a drip ( `/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/drip.ogg` ), and the previous one is still located at (`/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg`).

My issue is that at the gnome-terminal, when autocompleting or pressing left **BOTH** sounds are reproduced, at the same time. I want to just have `ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg` active, **not both**.

At the moment I have been only able to reduce the volume of the alerts (but still both are played), or turn the alerts down (but I dislike both "solutions").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seems due to upgrade from Ubuntu18.04 to Ubuntu18.10, left some folders remained.
but if its a fresh install of Ubuntu18.10 does not have the folder `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/`

```
$ ls /usr/share/sounds/
alsa  freedesktop  gnome  sound-icons  speech-dispatcher  Yaru
$
```

[image]

so, take backup of `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu` folder and then delete it from the folder `/usr/share/sounds`

[image]

[image]

[image]

***how to produce your own sound theme?:***

in fresh install of Ubuntu when you open gnome-tweaks-> Appearence-> Sound -- you will see "Yaru & Default" as sound themes selectable.

to create your own theme.

copy paste the folder `/usr/share/sounds/Yaru` in the folder `/usr/share/sounds` and rename it as `myBell` or any other name as you wish.

change directory to `/usr/share/sounds/myBell`
rename the folder `Yaru` to `myBell`
open the file `index.theme` folder and change the content like below

```
[Sound Theme]
Name=myBell
Directories=myBell
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

now you can select your own sound theme "myBell" from the gnome-tweaks

[image]