# Custom sound theme for Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome, sound, themes

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 with the default GNOME desktop.  The Yaru theme is too quiet and I am trying to add some sound files to a new folder I created: /usr/share/sounds/MyTheme.  The problem is, I am not sure what the naming convention is for the sound files to be detected for the system, and I have tried looking online with no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1105515/739431 may be related..

Comment: Thank you.  That is helpful, but doesn't seem to solve the problem completely (some sound files are named appropriately in the new theme but still do not work).

Answer (score 3):

You could create a folder, for example in your home directory, called `MyTheme`. This directory should contain another directory called `stereo` and a file called `index.theme`. The index.theme file should contain the following:

```
[Sound Theme]
Name=MyTheme 
Directories=stereo

[stereo]
OutputProfile=stereo
```

Next would be, that you paste your soundfiles to the stereo folder. The sound files should be *.oga, *.ogg, or *.wav, or *.sound (not sure about that) filetype. **They have to be named like you can see here**: https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/all/yaru-theme-sound/filelist

Next would be that you create a folder in you home directory called `mytheme_1.0-1` with `mkdir mytheme_1.0-1` and then you need some more subdirectories. You can create them with

```
mkdir mytheme_1.0-1/usr 
mkdir mytheme_1.0-1/usr/share
mkdir mytheme_1.0-1/usr/share/sounds
```

Now you need to copy the directory you created first to the last subdirectory of the folder you created later with `cp -r MyTheme mytheme_1.0-1/usr/share/sounds/`

After that you need to create another subfolder called DEBIAN with

```
mkdir mytheme_1.0-1/DEBIAN
```

and then you need to edit a file inside of that folder with

```
gedit mytheme_1.0-1/DEBIAN/control
```

That file needs to contain something like:

```
Package: mytheme
Version: 1.0-1
Section: base
Priority: optional
Architecture: amd64
Depends: 
Maintainer: Your Name <you@email.com>
Description: MyTheme
```

Just save the file and run `dpkg-deb --build mytheme_1.0-1` in your home directory. Now you need to install the package you created. You can do this with `sudo dpkg -i mytheme_1.0-1.deb` from your home directory.
At last you can choose your sound theme using the gnome-tweak-tool.
If you want to uninstall the package just run `sudo apt purge mytheme`.

Good luck

Comment: This links could help you to understand the naming convention for the sound files to be detected by the system: http://0pointer.de/public/sound-naming-spec.html also interesting: http://0pointer.de/public/sound-theme-spec.html from here: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/sound-theme-spec/

Comment: Thank you, Ill give this a try

Comment: You should edit this answer, because the document you're linking to, no longer exists. That's also why it is better to include it in your answer instead of just linking.